# Xamarin - prevent new ios 13 sheet style presentation

Tags: xamarin, ios13, uimodalpresentationstyle

Is there any way to avoid the new presentation sheet style introduced on ios 13?

I am trying to do that in my CustomNavigationRenderer, without lucky

```
    public class CustomNavigationRenderer : NavigationRenderer
    {

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            base.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen;
...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you look [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle?language=objc) you can see `UIModalPresentationAutomatic` defaults to `UIModalPresentationPageSheet`. Just change your modalPresentationStyle to `UIModalPresentationFullScreen`.

First create your new viewcontroller. **This** needs to have the modalPresentationStyle property set.

```
var modalViewController = new UIViewController();
modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen;
```

Then, present this viewController on top of the NavigationPage. `NavigationRenderer` has a property called `ViewController`:

```
this.ViewController.presentViewController(modalViewController, true, nil);
```